# Prism/CAL and WIn7 Taskbar Grouped Thumbnails/Preview

Tags: wpf, windows-7, prism, taskbar

So I'm using Prism v2 (CAL) in an app with four separate modules, loaded as tab controls. Works great so far. Quesiton(s): How do I have one grouped taskbar icon in Win7 for each tab, and how do I get 4 taskbar preview windows to display (one showing each tab control's contents, like in IE8)?

If it helps, this is how I'm loading my tab modules in the Bootstrapper:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
        {
            ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
            catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module1));
            catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module2));
            catalog.AddModule(typeof(MFLModule3));
            catalog.AddModule(typeof(Module4));

            return catalog;   
        }
```

I understand the basics of the WindowsAPICodePack (I think), but I don't know the best way to integrate that with Prism. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a few terms here.  Modules contain views and it is actually those views you want to provide previews for.

There are a number of things you could do here.  Very few of them are in any way related to Prism directly. If you are using a Region to host your views as tabs:

```
<TabControl RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion />
```

Then you could possibly create a RegionAdapter that automatically added previews to the windows for any Views in the region.  Here's some information about RegionAdapters here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707884.aspx

As for the previews themselves, I found this Coding4Fun article particularly helpful:

http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2009/08/25/9874533.aspx